# Open folder containing file and highlight it

Tags: java, file, io

I'm needing to open a folder containing the specified file, and highlight this said file. I have been looking for this for long but I have been unlucky. Could someone explain how this could be done using java?

Would be much appreciated. I am able to open files, folders, but not open the containing folder and highlighting a file. Cross platform code would be a plus, or just point me to the direction! Thanks!

@UPDATE:

Basically I'm doing an image sorter. I have a `ArrayList` containing filenames, e.g. myarraylist.get(0) would return funny_cat.jpg

This can be a handy functionality to have in a program that works with files/folders. It's easy enough to actually open the containing folder using:

I want the user to be able to open the currently selected item in a `JList` and open the containing folder with the target file selected.

I would post the code but it is too long and most unnecesary for this question, I will however post below how I open an explorer window, for the settings section of program, in order to choose a new directory to use:

```
public void browseFolder(){

     System.out.println("browsing!");

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

        File dir = new File(core.Loader.path);

        fc.setCurrentDirectory(dir);

        // Windows and Mac OSX compatibility code
        if (System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Mac OS X")) {

            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        } else {
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
        }


        fc.setApproveButtonText("Choose directory");
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(fc);

            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {


                File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
                // if the user accidently click a file, then select the parent directory.
                if (!f.isDirectory()) {
                    f = f.getParentFile();
                }

                // debug
                System.out.println("Selected directory for import " + f);

            }
}
```

@UPDATE

I have found the solution, will post as answer below.

Comment: What do you mean highlighting? Do you have some kind of UI?

Comment: Please clarify your problem a *lot*. Please show your current pertinent code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis i mean what happens exactly when you right click any file and click on "Open Containing Folder"; it opens an explorer.exe or finder.app window, in the path of the folder and the file, the one you clickled on, highlighted.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear post, clarified it and later I found my answer. Would like to post it as answer to this, thanks!

Comment: @ChristianFeo Uhh... What does `JFileChooser.setSelectedFile()` do? Seems like it should do the job.

Comment: @millimoose I am trying to do exactly that, except JFileChooser does not open a folder and select the target file (highlight it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I just called this method from the action performed and it does the trick.

Basically, the solution was to make this terminal command:

```
open -R absolute/path/to/file.jpg
```

This is for Mac OS X only, below is my method I use:

```
 public void openFileInFolder(String filename){

    try {
       Process ls_proc;

       String mvnClean = "open -R " + core.Loader.path + "/" + file_chosen;
       String OS = System.getProperty("os.name");

       System.out.println("OS is: " + OS);

       if (OS.contains("Windows")) {
           //code ...
       } else {
           ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mvnClean);
       }

     } catch (Exception e){
          System.err.println("exception");
     }
}
```